# разметка xml android studio

Tags: android, xml

как расположить Switch элемент под кнопкой?

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/mtrl_card_spacing"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/mtrl_card_spacing"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/mtrl_card_spacing"
            android:minHeight="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton

                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:id="@+id/material_text_button"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Settings"/>

                <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial

                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="Dark mode"/>

            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: использовать общий контейнер не вариант?

Comment: Оберните в `LinearLayout` с `android:orientation="vertical"`

Comment: Приведенная вырезка из разметки не имеет смысла. Измените ее, пожалуйста

Comment: Я обернул их в общий linear, но показывается одна кнопка, switch просто не отображается